# centos 7 merge sda1 and sdb1

Tags: linux, partitioning, centos-7

In my CentOS 7 server, there is one disk and one partition (sda, sda1) .
now it is full, i asked from server provider to add new disk (sdb) then i created a partition sdb1 with LVM type .
how can i merge sda1 and sdb1 without loosing data or boot corruption ?

fdisk -l output :

```
Disk /dev/sda: 42.9 GB, 42949672960 bytes, 83886080 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x000ab236

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *        2048    83886079    41942016   83  Linux

Disk /dev/sdb: 32.2 GB, 32212254720 bytes, 62914560 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk label type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x09a86f50

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1            2048    62914559    31456256   8e  Linux LVM
```

df -h output :

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs        1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs           1.9G  188M  1.7G  10% /run
tmpfs           1.9G     0  1.9G   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
/dev/sda1        40G   40G  623M  99% /
tmpfs           381M     0  381M   0% /run/user/54321
tmpfs           381M     0  381M   0% /run/user/0
```

Comment: You can't when sda1 isn't used as a PV (in the same VG as sdb1 is in). Consider moving everything to an LV (created on top of sdb1) first. dd, rsync, whatever way suits you best.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `vgextend` to extent the volume group and `lvextend` to extend the existing logical volume.
Assuming that sdb1 is already created as LWM:

```
# pvcreate <<newly created partition>>, or in our case
pvcreate /dev/sdb1

# Listing of curent volume group. 
# We will use later VG Name - so remember it somewhere (or copy-paste)
vgdisplay

# vgextend <<VG Name>> <<newly created partition>>, or in our case
vgextend cl_centos7 /dev/sdb1

# Scanning for psychical volumes (please notice our with 120GB)
pvscan

# Listing of logical volumes. 
# We want to extend this with name root and important info for us is LV path
lvdisplay

# Logical volume extending
# lvextend <<LV path>> <<newly created partition>>, or in our case
lvextend /dev/cl_centos7/root /dev/sdb1

# Logical volume extending for free space which we added by new disk
# resize2fs <<LV path>>, or in our case
resize2fs /dev/cl_centos7/root
```

Alternatively instead of 2 last commands you could use which extends the existing ДМ path to 100% of disk space:

```
# lvextend -l +100%FREE /dev/cl_centos7/root
```

[image]

Comment: `/dev/sda1        40G   40G  623M  99% /`